# Do I have to use regex to extract message or is there property?

Tags: ios, regex, swift

I have the following function defined inside delegate of push notification.

```
func pushManager(pushManager: AWSPushManager, didReceivePushNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    print("Received a Push Notification: \(userInfo.description)")
    let x = userInfo.description
}
```

This function is called whenever my app receives push notification. The description property of userInfo contains push message and it is in this format : "[aps: {\n    alert = ;\n}]  ". I'm wondering what is the best way to get the message part. I could use regex to extract the message part, but I'm not sure about the pattern that mataches the message. Is that even a proper way? I'm thinking if there is a function that returns clean message.

Answer (score 0):

The format of aps is JSON. You need to serialize "userInfo" to JSON format. For this, you can use a Framework like SwiftyJSON:

```
let json = JSON(userInfo)
```

Now you can access to APS like that

```
print(json["aps"])
```

You can initialize your JSON with standard function (included in Swift) however, you need to convert userInfo to data first.

Comment: Thanks. After integration,  I get "compiled with newer version of Swift language (3.0) than previous files (2.0) for architecture armv7". Probably because my project uses older version of swift 2.3 and the library is built with Swift 3. I can't upgrade my project since Amazon Web Service framework is in Swift 2 and upgrading will breaks everything.

Comment: You can use default function in order to serialize JSON